# Generalization of Fubini's Theorem for joint probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be aprobability space and $X, Y$ random variables, mapping from said space to $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{C})$ and $(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{D})$, respectively.

There is a generalization of Fubini's theorem for joint distributions:

$$\int_{\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}} f(x,y) \mathbb{P}(dx, dy)= \int_{\mathcal{X}}\int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(x, y) \mathbb{P}_{Y\mid X}(dy, x) \mathbb{P}_X (dx)$$

It seems that this theorem can only hold for product-like sets, i.e., sets of the form $C \times D$ where $C\in\mathcal{C}$ and $D\in \mathcal{D}$.

1.) However,
I would like to get a generalized version for general sets $E\in \mathcal{C}\otimes\mathcal{D}$. Is this possible? If so, how could this look like?

2.) A partially related question: if in the above equation $f$ was the indicator function over some set $E\in \mathcal{C}\otimes\mathcal{D}$, how do I integrate interatedly over that indicator function $\chi_E(x,y)$? This question is not necessarily restricted to the above equation but just in general: How to interatedly integrate over an indicator function of several (here: two) arguments?

Comment: This is what is called disintegration. You can find this in several Probability books, for example Kallenberg, O., Foundations of Modern Probability Theory, Third Edition.

Comment: Once you have proven result for functions of the form $f(x,y)=\mathbb{1}_A(x)\mathbb{1}_B(y)$ with $A$ and $B$ measurable, the result extends to all functions of the form $\mathbb{1}_E(x,y)$ with $E$ measurable in $\mathcal{C}\otimes\mathcal{D}$ by monotone class arguments. Then extend ti simple functions and to all bounded measurable functions through monotone convergence arguments.

Comment: thank you for your answers. What do you mean by monotone class arguments?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system) for example.